# RPM of two 300rpm motors is not equal, what to do?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I have two 300 RPM motors. But one moves slightly slower. Hence the robot does not move exactly straight. I tested various PWM values and now I am getting very less angle of turn. i there any other way by which the robot would always go straight?

Comment: Even if motors run at the same speed, if each drives a different wheel, tyre wear will guarantee you won't run straight. You need feedback - measure position or direction, and correct the steering accordingly.

Comment: since you have mentioned that they are dc motors, lower slightly the voltage to the faster motor. One way to do it is to put a diode(s) in series or a low value resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here:

- a driveshaft. Simply connect left and right wheels, just like a car.
- use synchronous motors and adjust your hardware to send the same signals to each
- add some intelligence to the controller. Worn parts or uneven surfaces will eventually require this option anyway.

Comment: A car uses a differential and not a fixed axle.

Comment: He's welcome to put gears in there if he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed difference is constant, you could increase the diameter of the slower wheel. Try wrapping the outer perimeter of the slower wheel with a layer of thick duct tape. Keep adding more layers of tape until you get very close to straight motion, then use thinner tape on the (now, maybe not the same as originally) slower to get them as closely matched as you need.